# ROW NUMBER CONDICIONAL

Tags: sql

Bom dia Pessoal,
Estou com uma coluna em select nomeada como "ROW" que inicia uma sequencia numérica (1,2,3...[que as vezes pode passar de 100]) quando todas as colunas que estão partition são iguais, e quando diferentes a sequencia volta a 1 e será reiniciada a partir dele quando as colunas se igualarem novamente.

*Objetivo:*
Fazer com que a coluna ROW inicie a contagem somente quando a diferença na coluna "DATHOR" for maior que 00:20.
Em outras palavras, não deixar  uma parada (latitu e longit iguais) inferior a 20 minutos iniciar uma sequencia.

**Atualmente:**

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║PLACA  ║          DATHOR            ║       LATITU        ║         LONGIT         ║    ROW    ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 04:50:00    ║  -27,0960066666667  ║     -52,6380843333333  ║     1     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 04:32:00    ║  -27,0960966666667  ║     -52,6380933333333  ║     1     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 04:02:00    ║  -27,0961566666667  ║     -52,6380950000000  ║     2     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 03:39:00    ║  -27,0961566666667  ║     -52,6380950000000  ║     1     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 03:35:00    ║  -27,0961466666667  ║     -52,6381016666667  ║     2     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 03:25:00    ║  -27,0961466666667  ║     -52,6381016666667  ║     1     ║
║AAA1111║     2021-02-10 03:23:00    ║  -27,0963583333333  ║     -52,6381350000000  ║     1     ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

**Ex do objetivo:**

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═══════╗
║PLACA..║..........DATHOR............║.......LATITU........║.........LONGIT.....║..ROW..║
╠═══════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════╣
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 04:50:00....║..-27,0960066666667..║ -52,6380843333333..║...1...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 04:32:00....║..-27,0960966666667..║ -52,6380933333333..║...1...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 04:02:00....║..-27,0961566666667..║ -52,6380950000000..║...2...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 03:39:00....║..-27,0961566666667..║ -52,6380950000000  ║...1...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 03:35:00....║..-27,0961466666667..║ -52,6381016666667  ║...1...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 03:25:00....║..-27,0961466666667..║ -52,6381016666667  ║...1...║
║AAA1111║.....2021-02-10 03:23:00....║..-27,0963583333333..║ -52,6381350000000  ║...1...║
╚═══════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

`SQL:`

```
SELECT
v.PLACA, 
v.DATHOR, 
v.LATITU,
v.LONGIT, 

ROW_NUMBER()    
    OVER    (PARTITION BY 
            v.LATITU
             ,v.LONGIT
             ,v.PLACA 

          ORDER BY 
            v.PLACA
            ,v.DATHOR   ASC
        ) 
as ROW 

FROM posicoes v
```

obs: não consegui editar corretamente, se alguém poder me ajudar na edição também para melhor entendimento fico agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando uma CTE recursiva para obter a coluna "row":

```
WITH
  CTE_RN AS
  (
    SELECT
      PLACA,
      DATHOR,
      LATITU,
      LONGIT,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PLACA ORDER BY DATHOR) AS RN
    FROM POSICOES
  ),
  
  CTE_REC AS
  (
    SELECT
      PLACA,
      DATHOR,
      LATITU,
      LONGIT,
      RN,
      1 AS ROW,
      DATHOR AS DATINI
    FROM CTE_RN
    WHERE
      RN = 1
      
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      N.PLACA,
      N.DATHOR,
      N.LATITU,
      N.LONGIT,
      N.RN,
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          C.LATITU = N.LATITU AND 
          C.LONGIT = N.LONGIT AND 
          DATEDIFF(MINUTE, C.DATINI, N.DATHOR) > 20
        THEN C.ROW + 1
        ELSE 1
      END,
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          C.LATITU = N.LATITU AND 
          C.LONGIT = N.LONGIT
        THEN C.DATINI
        ELSE N.DATHOR
      END
    FROM CTE_REC AS C
    INNER JOIN CTE_RN AS N
      ON
        N.PLACA = C.PLACA AND 
        N.RN = C.RN + 1
  )

SELECT
  PLACA,
  DATHOR,
  LATITU,
  LONGIT,
  ROW
FROM CTE_REC
ORDER BY 
  PLACA,
  DATHOR DESC
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Deu o erro abaixo:Mensagem 530, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 13
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Experimente acrescentar no final: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);`

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que a resposta ajudou. Avalie por gentileza a possibilidade de aceita-la como uma resposta.